# Best practices for frontend deployment with webpack

Tags: reactjs, webpack, deployment, frontend, web-deployment

I'm new to webpack, and front end development in general and am using `create-react-app` for my front end application which uses webpack under the hood to create a `/build` directory with the optimized production files. What is the best practice for deploying the optimized prod files to my server?

My current process entails :

1. Make code changes
2. Run `npm run build` to create the optimzed prod files
3. Commit to git
4. Deploy to server

Is it considered bad practice to never commit the `/build` directory (only commit my source code) and just have my CD server run `npm run build` and deploy the optimized prod files?

Comment: there's no point to commit the `/build` as far as I'm concerned, so it's not bad practice at all, since everyone can just build it by themselves, no need to commit it to the repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, the build folder is not pushed to git, as anyone who pulls the source should be able to generate everything in that folder.

If you push the build folder, you'll likely run into a lot of merge conflicts over minified files/chunks and references to them. Not worth the headache unless there is something to gain from having /build in the repo

Comment: If I ignore /build in my .gitignore, well webpack still compile it for production, say when I push it to Heroku?

Comment: webpack doesn't care what's in your repository, just whats on the local machine, so yes it will still compile the same as it did before. When you deploy, you will want to deploy the compiled files, or include build steps to compile them on whatever service you're deploying to